# Boundedness of one-dimensional Sobolev functions

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Are all Sobolev functions in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})$ essentially bounded?

Could any one tell me is this correct or give me an example of a function which belongs to $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})$ but is not essentially bounded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a special case of Theorem 7.34 from G. Leoni's 'A First Course in Sobolev Spaces', Second Edition. I'll give the proof of what you want; it already contains the main steps to prove the full Theorem.

For $p=\infty$, the conclusion is contained in the assumptions. For $p<\infty$,  By a similar proof to the following link, $C^\infty_c$ functions are dense in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R)$:

> [$C^1_c$ functions are dense in Sobolev space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3588684/80734)

So lets assume $f$ is in $C^\infty_c$. Let $\ell>0$, let $x\in\mathbb R$ be arbitrary and consider the interval $I_x=(x-\ell/2,x+\ell/2)$. By the continuity of $f$, there is $x_1\in \overline{I_x}$ such that $|f(x_1)|=\inf_{\tilde x\in I_x} |f(\tilde x)|$. Then
$$f(x) = f(x_1) + \int_{x_1}^x f'(y)dy$$
so that
$$ |f(x)| \le \frac{1}{\ell} \int_{I_x} |f(y)|dy + \int_{I_x} |f'(y)|dy \le \ell^{-1/p}\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)} + \ell^{1-1/p} \|f'\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}.$$
Since $x$ is arbitrary, this proves that any $f\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb R)$ is indeed bounded.

One can choose $\ell$ so that the two terms have equal contribution i.e. 
$$ \ell^{-1/p}\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)} = \ell^{1-1/p} \|f'\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)} \iff \ell = \frac{\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}}{\|f'\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}}$$
which leads to the following special case of the very useful Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation inequality -

$$ \|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R)} \le 2 \|f'\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}^{1/p}\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}^{1-1/p}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I cannot seem to figure out why $f \in C^\infty_c$ satisfies the following inequality you mentioned:

$\frac{1}{\ell} \int_{I_x} |f(y)|dy + \int_{I_x} |f'(y)|dy \le \ell^{-1/p}\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)} + \ell^{1-1/p} \|f'\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}.$
Could you tell me a little bit more in detail about this?

Comment: @HiroyukiTahara Yes, I can: this is nothing but Holder's inequality applied twice. The first one is $$ \int_{I_x} |f| =  \int_{I_x} |f|\times 1 \le \|f\|_{L^p(I_x) } \|1\|_{L^q(I_x)}$$  where $q$ is the Holder conjugate i.e. $1/q = 1-1/p$. Then
$$  \|1\|_{L^q(I_x)} = (\int_{I_x} 1^q)^{1/q} = |I_x|^{1/q} = \ell ^{1-1/p}$$
this cancels with one power of $\ell$; the second term is exactly the same (but without this cancellation)

Comment: Thank you! I haven't noticed Holder's inequality can be applied in these ways.
I also very much appreciate your nice proof of the special case of Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation inequality :)

Comment: @HiroyukiTahara You're welcome! I like it very much too, but credit should really go to the book author G. Leoni :) :)