# What is the relationship between $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ or is there one?

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have a function $u\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$, is it true that $u\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$? I know that $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}) = H^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, since $p=2$ (i.e. this is simply a Hilbert space of order 1).

I would imagine that since $u\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$, which means that $Du$ exists and belongs to $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, it means that it couldn't possibly belong to $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ since the norms on $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R})$ are defined for $1\leq p < \infty$ and for $p=\infty$, separately.

Help me out with understanding this please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boundedness of one-dimensional Sobolev functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589247/boundedness-of-one-dimensional-sobolev-functions)

Comment: @coudy I am attempting to understand that post, but it would be helpful to see the full text of the theorem referenced. I don't have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case $p=2$ admits a short proof using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
$$
f(x)^2 = f(0)^2 + {1 \over 2} \int_0^x f'(t)f(t) dt,
$$
$$
f(x)^2 \leq f(0)^2 + {1 \over 2} \|f'\|_2 \|f\|_2 
$$
and the bound does not depend on $x$.

Comment: Concise and clever and I wish I'd thought of it!

Comment: This is quite nice, but couldn't I simply use the idea that if $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ then the Sobolov space $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ embeds into $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ as long as $\frac{n}{k}\leq p$? Clearly this holds in the $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$ case, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.